# Borderlands 2 after level 30

Tags: borderlands-2

I am in the middle of playing Borderlands 2 and I am at level 31. I killed HJ and got the pirate treasure. I am unable to kill [Terramorphous the Invincible](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Terramorphous_the_Invincible) yet and cannot yet kill [Hyperius the Invincible](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Hyperius_the_Invincible). I have done all of the missions except one or two in the beginning (around level 10-15). I have a bunch of eridium, no eridium weapons and my questions are:

- Crazy Earl no longer has anything to sell, why am I still getting eridium? Is there another E vendor?
- What is the best course of action if I wish to continue to play the game?
- Where should I go to find places with loot that are level 30 and above?
- I really like playing and wish to continue, but is there any way to do so without going to true vault hunter mode?
- If I do go to True Vault Hunter mode, do the levels start at level thirty?

Comment: You are asking a lot of unrelated things here. You should consider picking one and making it into a question (Are there other eridium vendors for example). If you still have questions after that, make another question.

Comment: "*If I do go to True Vault Hunter mode, do the levels start at level thirty?*" See [What factors determine enemy levels or: How do enemy levels scale to the player character's?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/89690/4797)

Answer (score 21):

> Crazy Earl no longer has anything to sell, why am I still getting eridium? Is there another E vendor?

No, but Terramorphous costs 4 and both Hyperius and Master Gee cost 8 each.

> What is the best course of action if I wish to continue to play the game?

If you want to continue levelling you need to move on to TVH mode. You can always switch back later to complete all the side missions and challenges

> Where should I go to find places with loot that are level 30 and above?

Playthrough 1 is capped at 30, though you might see the odd 31/32 in tough areas. You need TVH mode.

The 3 raid bosses are always level 50, but you won't scratch them at level 30 and you won't level up to 50 in 30 areas.

> I really like playing and wish to continue, but is there any way to do so without going to true vault hunter mode?

Not really, though you could start a new character.

> If I do go to True Vault Hunter mode, do the levels start at level thirty?

Yes, enemies in TVH scale from 30-50 and the missions reset. You can switch between TVH and normal mode in the character selection dialog, and you keep all your kit between the two.

You have nothing to lose going to TVH mode, as you can always go back, and its the only way to gain levels. Also the gameplay changes - using the right elemental type becomes much more important and ammo becomes very expensive, so it's a new challenge.

Comment: +1 for multiple answers and for pointing out what I suspect the OP missed - that starting in TVH mode does not mean you can no longer play in 'normal' mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you start the second play through, which is what they are calling Vault Hunter mode, then you will start at the current level you are now and all the areas scale from there normally. Your character will keep all stats and all weapons they have on them. From that point you should be able to get to the level cap by your second play through.

Comment: Might want to mention that you will still be able to go back and continue your first playthrough while you're doing true vault hunter mode. No worries about losing that progress. Besides, right near the start the drops in true vault hunter mode will blow all the normal equipment out of the water. Plus you get to bring them back to normal mode if you ever feel like running around shooting things brainlessly for a bit.

Comment: @Seyren They're certainly brainless when I've finished shooting them.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider getting the Pirate DLC, if you have not. Enemies are at about Level 30.

Comment: This isn't completely true.  Enemies (and quests) scale to your current level for DLC.