# How to kill the W4R-D3N?

Tags: borderlands-2

This machine is madness.Takes approximately 1/100 of its SHIELD and a tiny bit more damage on the shield when i shoot the red eye with my shock sniper rifle.All these crazy flying surveyors and this one badass loader already chunking my health like crazy when i have a 600 health shield.

How in the world am i suppose to destroy the W4R-D3N if im already taking serious damage from a badass loader.

FYI im a lv 14 siren.Any tips?
Im in need of dire help..

Comment: This is a good question. We played as 3 and though I could revive anyone instantly with my action skill, it took us 20-30 minutes. Yet I cannot imagine how to solo this without playing Krieg.

Comment: Seriously? I beat him solo as Gaige (though I did need 2 or 3 second winds) and I'm fairly certain the fight was over in less than 10 minutes; Roland and Deathtrap helped. I'll admit though, W4r D3n was pretty much the hardest fight I've come accross yet (I haven't progressed very far yet; too busy playing other games). Still, this is a good question, so have a +1.

Comment: Nolonar: I mistook W4R-D3N for BNK3R which a completely different enemy far more into the game. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: I just started a new game as Gaige, and if you have enough anarchy stacks and a good damage shotgun, you can chunk even badass enemies for most, if not all of their HP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

W4R-D3N can be tricky if you're solo'ing the game and aren't playing one of the classes that has a "bullet sponge" as an action skill.  There are a few things you can do to make this easier, though.

First, since this is playthrough 1 and you've got lots of easy levels to gain, you might consider grinding a few levels.  Your damage output is somewhat affected by the level difference between you and an enemy, so you'll likely find it much easier to take him down if you're a few levels higher.  If you've skipped any side missions, now is a good time, or you could fight back through the Ramparts a time or two.

Second, you might want to consider rapid fire weapons for this fight.  There's not a lot of room to maneuver, and there's a lot of things vying for your attention.  Don't get me wrong - it's certainly possible to do this with a sniper, but you might have an easier time with something you can quickly fire an entire clip from and then dodge afterwards.

Also, possessing a corrosive and/or slag weapon goes a long way.  Loaders and Constructors are common enemies from here on out, and they go down so much easier with a good corrosive weapon.  Grinding, gambling, shopping, and opening the golden key chest are all good things to do to find some better/different weapons.

When W4R-D3N calls for backup and badass loaders spawn, put something between you and the boss, and focus on these loaders instead.  At least take down the badasses before you return your attention to the boss directly.  You can use the cover strategically to keep a large percentage of the enemies from targeting you at once.

Finally, the weaker loaders can be de-fanged by shooting their arms and/or legs off.  Then you can leave them around to give you a quick way to get back up should W4R-D3N down you during the fight.

Comment: i thought the level of your enemies were reflected by your own level?

Comment: @PORO, not really.  The [long answer is here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89690/what-factors-determine-enemy-levels-or-how-do-enemy-levels-scale-to-the-player), but the short answer is the campaign missions and bosses have fixed levels.

Answer (score 2):

I beat him by ignoring most of the other badass guys and running behind him right away. There is a spot behind him, where the other threats will not harm you and you can grind his shield and health away.

Answer (score 1):

Run immediately at it, and get right in front of its eye, preferably with an explosive or corrosive weapon, and start unloading into its eye.  Each hit should be a critical (the eye is its weakness).  Ignore most other threats, but if you start to feel like you are going down, back up, throw all of your grenades at it, and then take down a few loaders to give you breathing room. Freeing Roland gives you a huge boost to your fighting skill.

The key is to go for Critical shots on all the loaders.

Comment: This worked for me (lvl 14 Gunzerker).  I found a blue launcher that did 704x3 explosive.  Ran up and unloaded the magazine into the eye (6 shots).  W4R-D3N was dead less than 10 seconds after the fight began.  I got killed, but there were smaller loaders around... and I had a launcher.

Answer (score 1):

I failed multiple times at LVL 16, read the input here, then went back to *grind few more levels* until I had 2 rocket launchers (yes, I am the gun brute class, rockets available at Sanctuary shops) with damage of 1200-1500.   I cleaned out the neighborhood (avoid the sensors that detect you and produce robots) then just rushed at the machine straight.   It died before I ran dry on the second launcher.  Brute force, no strategy.

Answer (score 0):

The method I have found although still not able to beat the battle is if you shoot its eye as it begins to create loaders then the process will stop. No loaders = Less hassle.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was equip myself with level 12 weapons:

- A powerful Shotgun
- A launcher
- A sniper rifle.

I picked at the loaders with my sniper rifle from afar, went in and finished them off with my shotgun. Then used my launcher to drain at that beast machine until its shield depletes. Used my grenades and shotgun to deplete the health bar.

And make sure you are fully equipped with ammo before battling this boss. Every single ammo count. I had to repeat this process like 3 times, because of the annoying respawning loaders.

I would say one of the hardest boss battles in the game.

Answer (score -1):

I was level 15 with an assassin and after failing a couple of times I think I found a really easy method. Take the most powerful shotgun you get your hands on, run up to the eye and just kill it in like 10 shotgun shots. I even died while doing it, but killed the boss while being down. Then I ran for the hills because of all the loaders still around.