# How to scale the bosses level to mine

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm a level 36, and I often farm for legendary weapons. The problem is, for example, when I did the clan wars mission (killing hodunks or zafords) the final battle I killed the hodunks. I was around level 20 then. Now when I farm for the legendary weapon he drops, he still is level 20 and drops the level 20 legendary weapon. My question is; how do I get the some of the bosses (tector, hunter hellquist, scorch, ect.) to scale to my level so I can get my level legendaries? 
(don't know if this matters but I have beat the game and killed the warrior many times).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/89690/42984

Comment: Short answer: finish the game, and re-play it on True Vault Hunter mode.

Comment: @fbueckert He should first do new game plus actually, since TVH is for 50+.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness That's Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode.  TVH is NG+.