# Weapon level cap for slot machines?

Tags: borderlands-2

I've been playing the slots a lot for weapons, but I've noticed that after level 30 I haven't been getting any guns above level 30. Before this, most of the time the guns were at my level. Is this supposed to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on the first playthrough (Normal Mode), then there is a level cap at level 30, for both enemies and loot. This includes slot machine rewards. See [What factors determine enemy levels or: How do enemy levels scale to the player character's?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/89690/4797) - for more info.

You might want to play on True Vault Hunter Mode (second playthrough) to get slot machine rewards that are scaled to your level.

Comment: That explains it, however when I sent to a new area I think I remember the enemies being higher level than 30.

Comment: @Crubleigh Is it still in the first playthrough (Normal Mode)? It is possible that some enemies might be a few levels higher than 30 in there.

Comment: Yes I am still in the first playthrough.